# Spree - Can't find _form.html.erb

Tags: spree

I am going over the spree tutorial and trying to override the product edit admin page in spree using Deface.  I cannot locate the following file path in spree:

spree/admin/products/_form.html.erb

Comment: Where are you looking at? Can you post your override please?

Answer (score 0):

From your Spree directory type:

```
ls `bundle show spree_backend`/app/views/spree/admin/products/_form.html.erb
```

That's where the file is located on your system.

Here is the source of the file from the latest Spree:

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.2.1/backend/app/views/spree/admin/products/_form.html.erb